# Dropdown, React Router and back button

Tags: reactjs, react-router

This small component changes URL when you select something from dropdown. Everything works correctly.. Except **back button**. Everything else changes if I press it but dropdown doesn't change.

How exactly?

- If I go to landing page, default value is *All*
- Now I select *Red*
- Now *Blue*
- *Red* again
- Finally *Blue*
- Now, if I click back button, dropdown always shows last selected value (*Blue* in my example)

**How to overcome this issue?**

---

```js
class MyComponent extends React.Component {

    constructor (props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            selected: {
                // This only affects dropdown if landing to page 
                value: this.props.params.color, // Get param from url 
                label: // Some irrelevant uppercase magic here
            }
        }
    }

    static defaultProps = {
        colors: [
            {value: 'all', label: 'All'},
            {value: 'red', label: 'Red'},
            {value: 'blue', label: 'Blue'}
        ]
    }

    render() {
        return ( 
            <Dropdown 
                options={this.props.colors} {/* All options */}
                value={this.props.selected} {/* Selected option */}
                onChange={this.handleSelect.bind(this)} 
            />
        )
    }

    handleSelect(color) {
        this.setState({selected: color})
        browserHistory.push(`/${color.value}`)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that you are using state to manage the `selected` prop of your `Dropdown` component, however the router does not update this when you navigate back / forward.

Instead remove state entirely from your component and use the router to detect the `selected` item directly:

```js
import { find } from 'lodash';

class MyComponent extends React.Component {

    static defaultProps = {
        colors: [
            {value: 'all', label: 'All'},
            {value: 'red', label: 'Red'},
            {value: 'blue', label: 'Blue'}
        ]
    }

    getSelected() {
        const colours = this.props.colours
        const selectedColour = this.props.params.colour

        // Find the option matching the route param, or
        // return a default value when the colour is not found
        return find(colours, { value: selectedColour }) || colours[0];
    }

    render() {
        const selectedOption = this.getSelected();
        return (
            <div>
                <Dropdown 
                    options={ this.props.colors } {/* All options */}
                    value={ selectedOption } {/* Selected option */}
                    onChange={ this.handleSelect.bind(this) } 
                />
                <p>You selected: { selectedOption.label }</p>
            </div>
        )
    }

    handleSelect(color) {
        browserHistory.push(`/${color.value}`)
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome! What if there was a `<p>{this.getSelected()}</p>` under `<Dropdown>`? How to make it work so that `getSelected()` doesn't run 2 times?

Comment: Add the output to a variable and pass that to `Dropdown` instead: `const selected = this.getSelected()`. Updated the answer to clarify.